# Dotfile Management Tool, for controlling which dotfiles at work vs at home

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, version-control, configuration-management

I have several different environments I work in, and several different sets of dot-files I use in each.

### Use-Case

Consider the example (simplified scenario).
I have 3 environments:

- **work-desktop**
- **work-server**
- **home-desktop**

and I have some dotfiles, which I want to replicate in different environments.

- `.tmuxrc` -->  **work-desktop**, **work-server**, **home-desktop**
- `.fish/` -->  **home-desktop**
- `.subversion/` --> **work-desktop**, **work-sever**
- A different `.zshrc` for each of **work-desktop**, **work-sever** and **home-desktop**
- one `.vimrc` for **work-desktop** and **work-server**, and another `.vimrc` for **home-desktop**

Later I might like to change thing so that, I have one `.vimrc` for everywhere (when I update my homeone to use vundle, and unbreak vim's python compat at work).

---

### Requirements:

- **Must** support specifying different files for different environments
- **Must** support some files being shared across some environments
- **Must** avoid me having to manually copy files and then symlink them back
- **Should** commit to version control when triggered
- **Should** pull from version control when an update is called.
- **Should** support git
- **Would** be nice if it supported other version control (like SVN, and Hg)
- **Would** be nice if its config file for specifying which files got to which environments took a list of hostnames, but other solutions to the exist.
- **Don't care** if it is dependent on anything (A lot of .dotfile management tools i looked at advertised not being dependent on anything but the shell)
- **Must** work on all flavours of Linux (but I don't really care about Mac).
- **Must** be Free and Open Source.

I hard a close look at [RCM](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rcm-for-rc-files-in-dotfiles-repos), but I am not sure that it meets my version controlling requirements.
I also had shorter looks at [GNU STOW](http://brandon.invergo.net/news/2012-05-26-using-gnu-stow-to-manage-your-dotfiles.html?round=two) and [Dotbot](https://github.com/anishathalye/dotbot).

Answer (score 1):

There is [vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh) which does some crazy magic with multiple git repos that have your home as the working directory, and their git's directories separate. But it seems too complex for my needs, I just keep a git repo somewhere else on my system and manually symlink what I need to it.

The arch linux wiki has a [great article on dotfiles](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dotfiles).

Comment: this asnwer doesn't directly repond to whether or not the program meets my listed requirements

Comment: I haven't used it, but it seems to me that it would. You would have to organize your dotfiles into different repositories, like it says in the readme. Then you can pick and choose which repos go into which machines. vcsh helps you perform actions on all the repos on one machine, so `vcsh pull` will update your dotfiles.

Comment: The readme has very little information. [The docs](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh/tree/master/doc) make it a little clearer how to use it.

Comment: here on Software Rec SE. we *very* strongly perfer aswers that come from experience.

Comment: Here on the internet we prefer nice people. It's what i've got. If you dont like it move on.

Comment: Hey dude, chill out, I figured you were new, and didn't know so I thought I would inform you (rather than downvoting). I should have posted the meta links but was in a rush.
Experince isn't required but it is prefered. 
See these posts: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong?rq=1
http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/326/how-important-is-personal-experience
and always: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality?lq=1

I wan't intending to come of overtly curt (I guess I did)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple bash or python scripting?  You could have *in your VCS* one each of `home.`, `wdesk.` and `wserv.` variant of each of the .files that you need to control, all in a single directory, and two simple scripts save_env and set_env plus a .env file on each system:

- `set_env` would set the .env and overwrite the .files with the *env*. versions *and you would probably wish to trigger a re-read of them with* `source` *or the equivalent for the file concerned*.
- `save_env` would use the .env value to overwrite the appropriate *env*. files with the current ones. You could then review any changes and commit to your VCS.

Running through your requirements:

- Will support just about any files that you might need
- Will support shared files
- Does avoid 95% of the manual operations
- Can commit to/pull from VCS if required
- Could take a list of hostnames
- Will work on all*most* Linux variants should work on Mac as well
- Free - Open Source if you choose.
- Flexible
- Fast
- Just not pretty and you have to do a little more work setting it up.

Comment: See requirement 3: **Must avoid me having to manually copy files and then symlink them back**
Building your own is always an option for all most all things, but I would rather not.

Comment: __manually__ a script doing it for you is not manually -  roll your own is _usually_ the best way if you have custom requirements.

Comment: you will have to inform the tool where you want what files anyway, so why not put that information in a script? It's about the same amount of work.